# Compute the Legendre symbol $(\frac{5}{p})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have to compute the Legendre symbol $(\frac{5}{p})$.

If $p=2$, it is immediate to see that we have $5 \equiv 1 (\mod{2})$. let $p$ an odd prime. By quadratic reciprocity we have $(\frac{5}{p})=(-1)^{p-1}(\frac{p}{5})$, so $(-1)^{p-1}=1$ and we have $(\frac{5}{p})=(\frac{p}{5})$. Thus, we have to analyze the cases $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$, $p \equiv -1 \bmod 5$ and $p \equiv 3 \bmod 5$.

But why the result in the book is
$$
1 \ {\rm if } \ p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 10
$$
and
$$
-1 \ {\rm if } \ p \equiv \pm 3 \bmod 10?
$$
How can we reach the number $10$?

Comment: I am not sure how you deduce the first step, I think this is only valid if $p$ is an odd prime too? But anyway $5 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ which is a square. Other than that, why do you only analyze $p \equiv 1,-1,3 \mod 5$? What about $p\equiv 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the book (what book?) gives the result modulo $10$ but note that **if $p$ is an odd prime**
$$
p\equiv\pm1\bmod5\Longleftrightarrow p\equiv\pm1\bmod10
$$
and
$$
p\equiv\pm3\bmod5\Longleftrightarrow p\equiv\pm3\bmod10
$$

Comment: My problem was exactly this one... I found the solutions mod 5, but i don't know why in the book "Elementary number theory, Group Theory and Ramanujan graphs", the authors use mod 10

Answer (score 1):

I will not prove every case, but I am going to show what is the idea we can use to prove that $\left(\frac{5}{p} \right)=1$ if $p \equiv \pm 1 (\mod 10)$. we can use the law of quadratic reciprocity, writing this Legendre symbol as:
$$
\left(\frac{5}{p} \right)=(-1)^{p-1}\left(\frac{5}{p} \right)
$$
Since $5 \nmid p$, thus $p\equiv 1,2,3,4 (\bmod 5)$.

First, consider $\left(\frac{5}{p} \right)=1$, then $\left(\frac{p}{5} \right)=\left(\frac{1}{5} \right)=1$ (that means $p\equiv 1 (\bmod 5)$) And $(-1)^{p-1}=1$ (that means $p\equiv 1 (\bmod 2)$). Solving the system:
$$
 \left\{
     \begin{array}{l}
       p \equiv 1 (\bmod 5) \\
       p \equiv 1 (\bmod 2)
     \end{array}
\right.
$$
Using the CRT, we get
$$
  p\equiv 1 (\bmod 10)
$$
And now, consider $\left(\frac{5}{p} \right)=1$, then $\left(\frac{p}{5} \right)=\left(\frac{4}{5} \right)=1$ (that means $p\equiv 4 (\bmod 5)$) And $(-1)^{p-1}=1$ (that means $p\equiv 1 (\bmod 2)$). Solving the system
$$
 \left\{
     \begin{array}{l}
       p \equiv 4 (\bmod 5) \\
       p \equiv 1 (\bmod 2)
     \end{array}
\right.
$$
We have
$$
 p\equiv -1 (\bmod 10)
$$
So, here we conclude that
$$
  \left(\frac{5}{p} \right)=1, \, if\, p\equiv \pm 1 (\bmod 10) 
$$
And you can continue using the same idea.

JOAQUIM CUMBE, email: armindojoaquim441@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'd want notation $\pmod {4p}$. To see why:

$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow p=1,4\pmod 5$

$\left(\frac{-5}{p}\right) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow p=1,3,7,9\pmod {20}$

This happens whever $a=2,3\pmod 4$ when evaluating the set of primes for which $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=1$. The Legendre symbol is the same for $±a$ whenever $p=1\pmod 4$ and different if $p=3\pmod 4$.